# Override inline style on hover then return

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, perl

I have some divs (.worker) that have inline styles generated through Perl. On hover, I want to change the background, then revert back to the Perl generated style. The only way to override the inline style of .worker is with jQ.css. Unfortunately, when I leave .worker, it stays as the overridden value. I tried to capture the style attribute and pass it as a parameter to the callback of .hover, but it does not work.

The Perl generated inline style: `$html .= qq(<div class="worker" style="background:linear-gradient(to bottom right,@{[bgc($_)]},black)">$_</div>);`

The jQ to override (then return to Perl):

```
$('.worker').hover(function(){
   var background = $(this)[0].style.background;
   $(this).css('background','#FF9500');
}, function(background){
     $(this).css('background',background);
```

This does not work as I mentioned, I think because the `var background` is scoped to the first function, and loses its scope for the callback.

Is there any way to return the original inline styles after changing them with .css?

EDIT: Thanks to @Banzay for the answer. However, now I have a connected issue. When I left/right click on a .worker div, I want the background to be white and color black. But because of the .hover() solution, the bgc changes to white onclick, but when I mouseout it goes back to the Perl generated background.

The code for the clicks:

```
var NoName = $('#name').val();
  $('.worker').click(function(){
    var boxName = $('#name').val();
    if (boxName != NoName && boxName.match(/\w/)) {
      $(this).html(boxName[0].toUpperCase() + boxName.substring(1)).css({'background':'white','color':'black'}).removeClass('worker').addClass('assigned');         
    }
  });

$('.worker').bind('contextmenu',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).html('-').attr('style','background:white').toggleClass('worker');
});
```

And the hover code:

```
$(".worker").hover(function(){
$(this).data('backgr', $(this).attr('style').split(":")[1]);
$(this).attr('style','background:#FF9500');
}, function(){
     $(this).attr('style','background:' + $(this).data('backgr'));
});
```

From the code, you can see I've tried to remove the worker class, add another class, and toggle the worker class. The issue is that the worker class is not removed, so when I move off the div after clicking, the .hover() is invoked resulting in the div reverting back to Perl inline style.

How do I remove the hover effect after a left/right click?

Comment: consider making the variable global  by putting it outside the function "var background = $(this)[0].style.background;"

Comment: @FridayAmeh That does work with `$('.worker')[0]` but now of course it grabs the first div with the class. Is there a way to grab the array number of the div hovered?

Comment: `var workingClass = document.getElementsByClassName("worker")[0];`

Comment: @FridayAmeh The `$('.worker')[0]` only gets the first instance of the class. I have 27 of them on the page (it's a schedule). That's why I tried to use `this`. It targets the div I hover. But there is no way that I can tell to reference the style to the callback or even to say `.mouseleave` or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can work around it by creating additional attribute for the element using `.data()` method. So you don't need to pass any parameters to callback function

Here is an example:

```js
$("#div1").hover(function(){
    $(this).data('backgr', $(this).attr('style').split(":")[1]);
    $(this).attr('style','background:' + ' linear-gradient(to bottom right,yellow,blue');
}, function(){
    $(this).attr('style','background:' + $(this).data('backgr'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom right,red,black);">This is a phrase</div>
```

Comment: That `.data()` thing is awesome. I did not know about that; thanks for teaching me something. I will definitely need to remember that trick.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand very well what you want to do but if you want to change the style when a hover happens you could do it from the CSS with a selector similar to this `.worker:hover { rules}`  even if you are using jquery you could add a class that changes the style when a hover happens something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.worker').hover(
        function() {
           $(this).addClass("second_class")
        },
        function(){
           $(this).removeClass("second_class")
        }
    );
});
```

with that when a hover happens you will not have to overwrite the properties of your worker class but apply another class

Comment: My issue is that the Perl generates the style specific to a div's content (name); therefore, it is an inline-style. I cannot apply a CSS style because I need different styles depending on the div's content. But, I want to change the background on hover. In order to change inline styles, I need the jQ. But once I change it on hover, it stays. I need a way to revert back to the Perl generated style. Take a look at the site: [link](http://charon.cs.wau.edu/~kwilliam/csdesk2)